# Dúvida com @Style.Render

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc, .net, single-page-application

Se eu coloco em minha *view* Layout essa linha:

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
```

Eu estou afirmando que todos os arquivos `.css` na pasta `Content` serão renderizados? Ou seja, eu não preciso colocar nenhum `.css` explicitamente em minha *view*, é isso? Se dentro da página houver 5 arquivos, os cinco serão renderizados e já incluso na minha *view*, é isso mesmo? Não precisamos de linhas como essa:

```
<link href="~/Content/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Para cada arquivo `.css` que tenho, estou entendo de forma correta?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esta linha apenas inserirá `site.css` que está em `/Content`. A não ser que configure para usar outros.

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include("~/Content/bootstrap.css", "~/Content/site.css"));
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/ASP.NET/StyleRender.cs).

[Documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

Quando usa o `Style.Render` não precisa colocar a carga explícita dos arquivos CSS porque ele colocará para você. Carregará tantos quantos forem configurados no código acima.